# SVN: is it possible to determine which branches a branch was merged into?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to determine which branches a branch was merged into (and at which GRN), given only the branch name?

example branch name:

`^/branches/FOO`

example result:

- FOO was merged into DEV_X_FOO at GRN X
- FOO was merged into DEV_X_BAR at GRN X

I can look backwards to get the ancestry using this command:

`svn propget svn:mergeinfo $SVNROOT/branches/FOO`

But how to look forwards to learn who inherits the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short way**

1. Get list of all branches
2. `svn mergeinfo FOO $SOME_BRACH` or maybe `svn --show-revs=merged mergeinfo FOO $SOME_BRACH` (no output means "no merges in this direction")

Sample with test-repo with a lot of different cross-branch merges (A>B, A>C, A>D, B>C, B>D, C>D and no inversed merges)

```
>svn --show-revs=merged mergeinfo A B
r3
r7
r8
r9
>svn --show-revs=merged mergeinfo A C
r3
r7
r8
r9    
>svn --show-revs=merged mergeinfo A D
r7
>svn --show-revs=merged mergeinfo B A
>
```

**Processing plain mergeinfo**

You can get (recursively) all mergeinfo data as usual SVN-property from branches root (even from repo, without WC) in single command for *any* amount of branches and collect all needed data. `svn pg` for the above repository, two forms (verbose and non-verbose)

```
branches>svn pg svn:mergeinfo -R
B - /branches/A:3-24
C - /branches/A:3-24
/branches/B:4-20
D - /branches/A:7
/branches/B:4-21
/branches/C:5-24

branches>svn pg svn:mergeinfo -R -v
Properties on 'B':
  svn:mergeinfo
    /branches/A:3-24
Properties on 'C':
  svn:mergeinfo
    /branches/A:3-24
    /branches/B:4-20
Properties on 'D':
  svn:mergeinfo
    /branches/A:7
    /branches/B:4-21
    /branches/C:5-24
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are over 6000 branches in this repository. This command outputs revs if there is any ancestor relationship (not just parent/child) which doesn't meet my requirement unfortunately. I really only want to know the exact branch(es) that was merged into and the GRN that this occurred in.

Comment: @ChrisJenn - use **only** `--show-revs=merged`, which doesn't show common ancestry?